# Find $a,b$ and $c$ from $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{a-x^2-(b-x^2)^2}{f_n(x)}=c$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Given the function in $x$
>
> $f_n(x)=sin^nx$ $(n=1,2,3,...)$,
>
> answer the following questions,
>
> (1) Consider the cases in which the equality
>
> $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{a-x^2-(b-x^2)^2}{f_n(x)}=c$,
>
> holds for three real numbers $a, b$ and $c$.
>
> (i) We have $a=b^O$.
>
> (ii) When $n=2$, if $c=6,$ then $b=\frac{P}{Q}$.
>
> (iii) When $n=4$, then $b=\frac{R}{S}$ and $c=-T$
>
> Find $O, P, Q, R, S$ and $T$.

I am working on my scholarship exam problem but not sure how I could start here, could you please give me a hint? Please assume my knowledge of high school maths. I don't need full solutions, probably just an idea or discussion would be enough. The answers provided are 2, 7, 2, 1, 2 and 1.

Comment: It's sufficient to just use the fact that $$\sin^n{(x)}=x^n+O(x^{n+2})$$ throughout this question.

Comment: How did you get this form? $\sin^n(x)=x^n+O(x^n+2)$

Comment: $$\sin{(x)}=x+O(x^3)$$$$\therefore \sin^n{(x)}=(x+O(x^3))^n=x^n+O(x^{n+2})$$

Comment: Apologies I mean how did you derive this from? Is it a general formula for $sin^n(x)$?

Comment: Just think of how you can multiply out the $n$ factors of $(x+O(x^3))$. Obviously the lowest possible power of $x$ is the $x^n$ term of which there is only one. Then, the next highest power of $x$ can be achieved by multiplying one $x^3$ coefficient by every other $x$ coefficient. There are many ways to do this but this just leaves $O(x^{n+2})$ as the trailing term.

Comment: Your way is interesting. This might be an innocent question, but how did you get this term $x+O(x^3)$. Where did it come from? I could not relate this to the question.

Comment: This part $O(x^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use
$$ a-x^2-(b-x^2)^2=(a-b^2)+(2b-1)x^2-x^4,\sin x=x+O(x^3). $$